# Definite article 'the' with virtual things (software and in general)

Tags: articles, definite-article

I'm a bit too much confused about the real use of 'a/the' articles.

I've recently read articles about compressors (it's a hardware or software tool for audio) and have two questions.

1. They all start with *'a compressor'* and then go with *'the compressor'*, like in this example:

> **A** compressor includes several controls to help you control exactly how it behaves:
>
> **Threshold**
>
> The level where **the** compressor begins working is called **the** threshold—you set it with a dB control to determine the parts of the signal the compressor acts on.

So first we say *'a compressor'* because it's some abstract compressor, ok, then author says *'the compressor'* like it's something specific, but it's still **some** compressor that aren't even on my or author's computer.

And the same with the other mentioned things: *'the level'*, *'the threshold'*, *'the signal'* despite they wasn't even introduced. Btw, *'a dB control'* doesn't have 'the' for some reason.

My only idea is that once a compressor is introduced, we imagine it and all of its parts as real things.

2. Is this sentence correct?

> In most sounds, **the** transient is the loudest moment in **the** signal.

As I understand, without *'In most sound'* it would be *'**a** transient is the loudest moment in **a** signal'*, but *'most sounds*' makes it specific?

The article I'm mentioning: https://blog.landr.com/how-to-use-a-compressor

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fairly common in English that definite and indefinite articles can be confusing, and are sometimes used in arbitrary ways. Technical writers struggle to be precise in determining which to use.

The only time when the definite article is required is when there is only one of something, as in the example -- the transient is the loudest moment... (there can be only one 'loudest').

As you show in the example, when speaking of a device or a piece of software, it is common for an indefinite article (a) to be used on first reference, and then to use the definite article when the focus has shifted to describing aspects of the item, in a sense making it into a specific item (even though it may be a generic or theoretical one).

It could probably go either way, however. Here are two examples where the articles are switched between definite/indefinite and some are left out:

A cow is an animal that produces milk. To collect the milk, a farmer places a bucket below the cow's udder...

The cow is an animal that produces milk. To collect milk, the farmer places the milk  bucket below a cow's udder.

Neither one would be that hard to understand, I don't believe. One may seem more natural or correct, but that could depend on the surrounding sentences and even the tone and style of the writing.

Comment: Thanks! It explains a lot